# Windows Media creation USB not booting

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, gpt

I used this abomination of tool to create a bootable usb I already have experience in this kind of things so I went pretty confident, then the usb wasn't booting. I checked if it was recognized by the BIOS and it was, I checked legacy support and it was enabled so I tried creating another USB with Rufus in gpt mode partition, still nothing, I even set to default all the UEFI settings. Fun fact: any Linux iso I have in my server boots just fine

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here, simply a complaint.

Comment: Well my bad, obviously I want to install Windows and I can't figure it out, I even tried window 7 iso and just works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like Windows ISO problem, corrupted or something. I experienced such a problem. I suggest to get another ISO file through a reliable service like the Adguard one https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php, and try again. Rufus is good and it does the job.

Comment: If you wanted a source, you should had asked...

Answer (score 0):

You have stated in your comment that a Windows 7 ISO works fine.
You have not stated what utility you are using to flash the Windows 10/7 ISO with.
Because flashing a Win7 ISO works *fine*, we can eliminate the fact that your USB or your computer's UEFI settings are to blame.

It is possible that your flashing utility does not support Windows 10, in which case you can try another utility. It is also possible that your Win10 ISO is not bootable/is corrupted. In that case, you can either get a fresh copy of the ISO, or download another one. Google will help with this.

Comment: I'm using Windows Media creation tool as stated in the title, I tried both create a USB drive and downloading the iso and flashing it with Rufus. I also tried flashing w8.1 which if I'm not mistaken was the 1st Windows iso to only use gpt and worked just fine